# Regtest at height 120k took 600ms to generate a block

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, regtest

Just doing

```
while :
do
 time bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress 1 <non_local_wallet_address>
 bitcoin-cli getblockcount
done
```

brings regtest blockgen times up to 600ms when generating a block at the height 120k, even with all empty blocks.

I have noted down the following numbers:

```
height, gen-time
800 -> 7ms
5500 -> 18ms
11000 -> 31ms
22000 -> 65ms
37000 -> 110ms
```

and so on.

This makes my test suite slowing down a lot, over time.
Is this something we can deal with?

Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. The difficulty is the same in regtest, so I don't think this should be happening. 
Unfortunately, I cannot provide any more help apart from suggesting to restructure your suite so that it does use 120k blocks.

Comment: This is probably not related to block height. Because running `invalidate` and mining again from genesis does not help.

Comment: Why do you need 120k blocks for a test?

Comment: If you add `-debug=bench` to your `bitcoind` command, then the debug.log file will contain log lines with benchmarks for some part of the block generation process. That may help inform where the slow down is.

Comment: Hi Andrew, infrastructures developers may have infinite reasons for having a private, permanent, regtest network.
The debug (=all) doesn't highlight where bitcoincore is spending time to generate blocks. I'll try with bench.

Comment: Hey @JonSnow, have you had any luck with the benchmark tests? I am experiencing the same issue and before I start investigating on my own, I would like to hear if you found something! Thank you in advance!